# Add new column from ArrayList of Integer to CSV with Spark - Java

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I want to add a new column of values get from an array of Integers to a CSV read by Spark.

```
SQLContext context = new SQLContext(spark);
StructType customSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                    new StructField("sex", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
                });
int[] values= {31, 28, 31};
DataFrameReader read = context.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                    schema(customSchema).
                    option("header", true).
                    option("delimiter", ",");
Dataset<Row> csvDataset = read.load(path).withColumn("age", ...);
```

maybe it can be done with function withColumn(), but I don't know how to set the values.

Is there any way to do this?

```
+---+---+
|sex|age|
+---+---+
|M  |31 |
|F  |28 |
|F  |31 |
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve what you asked with Spark. Keep in mind that Spark treat data as distributed, that means the order of rows are arbitrary in both dataset so you can't match rows based on their orders.

My suggestions are:

- give some kind of id column in both of them and just simply join them.
- Or you can achieve this by simple read-write I/O operations

Answer (score 0):

Use [typedLit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#typedLit-T-scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag-) function.

Check below code.

```
dfa
.withColumn("age",explode(typedLit(values)))
.show(false)
```

Comment: I cannot apply the values to typedLit function

Comment: any specific reasons ?

Comment: The method typedLit(T, TypeTags.TypeTag<T>) in the type functions is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Comment: Your values is of type array of int, right ??.. typedLit will take any array of int values.

Comment: I think you need to convert from java types to scala type and then pass it to this function

Comment: How? I don't know Scala